# nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException JPA Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Hello i'm trying to save a row to my database well i have spend all the day on that save !
Here is my entities

OrderDetails entity : https://pastebin.com/HAGVUVEF

Category entity : https://pastebin.com/AWvbFKV0

When i'm trying at CheckoutSerive to save a list of OrderDetails to database i get the following error

```
2021-04-02 01:15:03.961 ERROR 9076 --- [o-8080-exec-111] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  :
Forwarding to error page from request [/user/checkout/process] due to exception [detached entity
passed to persist: coffeeshop.entity.Category; nested exception is
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:
coffeeshop.entity.Category]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist:
coffeeshop.entity.Category; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached
entity passed to persist: coffeeshop.entity.Category
```

Well i'm trying to save the list of OrderDetails by this method

```
    private void setOrderToOrderDetails(Orders order, List<OrderDetails> cart) {
    for (OrderDetails orderDetail : cart) {
        orderDetail.setOrder(order);
        orderDetailsRepo.save(orderDetail);
    }
}
```

Note that when i use the same method at cart's Controller it works perfectly,
i get the error above in just this case.
PS. If my OrderDetails object does not have any category in his categories list it is okay and the save is successfull

Comment: From order details remove (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) in the category property. It's trying to persist a category that is already persisted (so it's detached) in the database. You don't want to recreate a category because it's shared among other entities. Cascade ALL contains also PERSIST which will try to save category again.

Comment: Yeah that was the error! i replaced  (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) with @Cascade(value = {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DETACH,org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE}) and it works ! Thank you for your answer

Comment: Glad you solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From order details remove (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) in the category property. It's trying to persist a category that is already persisted (so it's detached) in the database. You don't want to recreate a category because it's shared among other entities. Cascade ALL contains also PERSIST which will try to save category again.

Fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66912311/nested-exception-is-org-hibernate-persistentobjectexception-jpa-spring-boot#comment118279427_66912311), thanks!